# Seek location when the jwplayer plays the FLV format video

Tags: jwplayer, flv, seek

I am using jwplayer version (7.4.3). In the case of seek positioning control, the video in MP4 format is ok, and the FLV format has a few seconds of error.
Don't know how to solve this problem?